# Issue connecting to Wifi

Tags: wireless

So I changed from Elementary OS to Ubuntu last weekend. I've been able to connect to my university's open Wifi, but for some reason I can't connect to the password-protected one there, and I can't connect to my house's password-protected either. I'm putting the correct password in, but it then keeps asking for the password while not connecting.

Comment: Which authentication method are the networks using? What do the logs say? `grep wlanInterface /var/log/kern.log`, replacing `wlanInterface` with the device name (`wlan0`?)